# Synonym of "s--t eating grin" suitable for polite company

Tags: synonyms, offensive-language

Can anyone think of a synonym for "[shit eating grin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29166/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-shit-eating-grin)" that would be usable in polite company?

This definition from the OED captures the meaning I'm looking for perfectly:

> A broad grin expressing uncontrollable delight or (self-)satisfaction, esp. characterized by awareness of having got away with something normally considered outrageous or improper.

As pointed out [in this Metafiler comment](http://ask.metafilter.com/177958/Etymologydefinition-of-shiteating-grin#2565905), an important nuance is that this sort of grin is uncontrollable.

Comment: *poo* eating grin?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One synonym for "shit-eating" is [smug](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/smug):

> looking or feeling too pleased about something you have done or achieved

So you can say that someone has a "smug grin" or a "smug look on their face". It still has the negative connotation of "shit-eating grin", but is suitable for polite company.

A related idiom is that one can look like [the cat that got the cream](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/canary):

> if someone looks like the cat that got the cream, they annoy other people by looking very pleased with themselves because of something good that they have done

Comment: Or "the cat that ate the canary" if you're American.

Answer (score 22):

It's a little obscure but…

> ...grin **like a Cheshire cat.**

fits the bill.

Comment: Oh, but Cheshire cat's grin is so much more! :D

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! I keep going back and forth on whether to accept simchona's answer or yours. :)

Comment: I like smug as well but felt that it has a negative connotation that doesn't necessarily apply. I've seen a s**t eating grin on my 4 year son when he's ridiculously happy. I think the saying has more to do with the expression on one's face as a literal interpretation of what your mouth would look like while trying to eat feces in a controlled fashion and feign enjoyment. It's akin to "say cheese", having a gun pointed at your privates, or just being given a piece of chocolate after you've cleaned up your Lego.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the word:

> **smirk**
>   verb (used without object)
>   1.
>   to smile in an affected, smug, or offensively familiar way.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit more wordy, but I suggest:

> You look like the cat that ate the canary.

Answer (score 2):

> A big, cheesy grin

*Cheesy*, as in "Say cheese!" but also as in,

> adj., cheap, unpleasant, or blatantly inauthentic.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I though of and as alluded to in your definition:

> a self-satisfied grin...